# How to keep current tabIndex when navigating between NextJS pages

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, tabindex

How to properly save current tabIndex when navigating between pages?

(In ideas to make a function that will save the current index in the sessionStorage and retrieve it when the page is mounted)

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: if it helped can you pls mark answer as correct answer ?

Answer (score 1):

a Simple solution based on the `useRouter` hook:

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";


export const MyNav = () => {

  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <ul>
      <li className={router.pathname == "/" ? "active" : ""}>
        <Link href="/">API</Link>
      </li>
      <li className={router.pathname == "/users" ? "active" : ""}>
        <Link href="/users">Users</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withRouter()` library to figure out current URL and match it with the page URL and then add a different class with `border` or `background-color` to differentiate between them

---

You can also go with a much easier method and use `:active` and `:visited` selectors of CSS with the `nav-item` class or element.